# What is the best method to implement function overloading in C?

Tags: c, function, polymorphism, overloading

I'm currently writing a header file `data_structures.h` that contains several different data structures such as dynamic arrays and trees. My problem is, that I want to have a function like `get_element()` that can be both called with an instance of a dynamic array or a tree or any other data structure.

I know that there is no such thing as function overloading in C, but are there any best practice methods to get around this problem? Would it be best to just have another function name for each data structure, for example `tree_get_element()`?

```
int get_element(struct dynarray *a, int index);
int get_element(struct tree *t, int index);
```

Comment: There is [_Generic keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) in C which allows for a limited form of overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be best to just have another function name for each data structure, for example `tree_get_element()`?

Yes, that is the way it's typically done in C.

But if you are using C11 compiler you can expand on this with generic expressions:

```
int dynarray_get_element(struct dynarray *a, int index);
int tree_get_element(struct tree *t, int index);

#define get_element(x, index)                   \
    _Generic((x),                               \
        struct dynarray *: dynarray_get_element,\
        struct tree *    : tree_get_element     \
    )((x), (index))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches of dealing with this problem in `C`:

(1) Use a `union` and each type of `pointer to user-class` [you can try a different character for each `union member` to let the function know which call you made];

(2) Use a `void *` as the `pointer to user-class` [in this case, you need to use a `char *` or string type in order to specify the type name].

Now, for instance, (1) would be coded as:

```
union _dynarrtr_ {
    struct dynarray *a;
    struct tree *t;
};
typedef union _dynarrtr_ UDynArrTree;

/*UATChar is either 'a' or 't' (or whichever other union members there are)*/
int get_element(char UATChar, UDynArrTree *UATPtr, int index);
```

And, (2) would be coded as follows:

```
/*Here, you can test 'typeStr' against the name of each type*/
int get_element(const char *typeStr, void *objPtr, int index);
```